# For vue data, is it necessary to define data or is it just convention

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

For vue data, for every tutorials I have seen, it seems that data variables first defined as return value when creating vue instance like below:

```
app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            someData: null,

        }
    },
}
```

I wonder if this practice is some way necessary or if it is just a convention, because I could simply define new data like this.someData2 in mounted or methods and it seems to work pretty much the same way.

Comment: Declaring data properties in `data()` make them reactive. *Attaching properties* inside `mounted`/`methods` would not automatically make them reactive.

Comment: @tony19 I've tried myself define this.someData = "some string"(w/o initially declared in data()) inside mounted and saw "someData" bound to a html tag getting updated. Isn't that what being reactive?

Comment: See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-h1pohp?file=src%2FApp.vue). Notice the attached prop is not reactive, while the data prop is.

Comment: @tony19 Tnx for the demo. I see that the attached property is not reactive. Actually it conflicts with my own testing result, but I guess it could have been reactive only limited to my own testing case, and not universally reactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I could simply define new data like this.someData2 in mounted or methods and it seems to work pretty much the same way ?*

Answer is Yes, You can add a new property directly to `this` without including it in `data`. However, properties added this way will not be able to trigger reactive updates.

But we use the `data` option to declare reactive state of a component. The option value should be a function that returns an object. Vue will call the function when creating a new component instance, and wrap the returned object in its reactivity system.

Please do through this official documentation of [`Reactivity Fundamentals`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html) for better understanding.

Comment: Tnx for the linked documentation. I now get that the purpose is on reactivity of data.

Answer (score 0):

the data option must be an function so every vue instance can maintain a separate copy of the return object，so it won't infect other instance

Comment: Do you mean that if I set this.someData, it would be shared between every instances? Isn't "this" is scoped to the particular vue instance where it is referenced?